# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:

Tags: php, laravel-5, session-cookies

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:

I get this error when my session expire .so when you refresh the browser i get this error how can i resolve the problem.

this error occurs in five of my blade.php files .when i am in those blade and refresh the browser i get this error .

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown nav-user">
    <a class="nav-link nav-user-img" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="assets/images/avatar-1.jpg" alt="" class="user-avatar-md rounded-circle"></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right nav-user-dropdown" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink2">
        <div class="nav-user-info">
            <h5 class="mb-0 text-white nav-user-name">
                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                {{ Auth::user()->email }}
            </h5>
            @csrf
            <span class="status"></span><span class="ml-2">Online</span>
        </div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user mr-2"></i>Account</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog mr-2"></i>Setting</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href= "{{ route('logout') }}" ><i class="fas fa-power-off mr-2"></i>Logout</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Check your user table if you have a column with this name and also check of your user table has data.

Comment: my user table has a column called name and the table has data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a user is logged in by using `Auth::check()`

So your blade part should look like:

```php
@if(Auth::check())
    <h5 class="mb-0 text-white nav-user-name">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
        {{ Auth::user()->email }}
    </h5>
@endif
```

Additionally if the visitor is not supposed to see this blade when he/she is not logged in you can add middle ware to your route

```php
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () { 
// your routes here
});
```

This will redirect users to the login page when the are not logged in.

Comment: i want it to log me out and sign in again  because after adding this one it is keeping in that page logged in and i want it to log me me out and login again because the session is expired

Comment: Why is the session expiring ? the answer i posted is a solution to the error in your question. If the session expires and you are still checking for a property on the logged in user you get the error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`

Comment: the error occur when the session expires .instead  of logging me out it give me that error.

Comment: Add `->middleware('auth');` to your route so the route can only be accessed by logged in users. [more info on assigning middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

Comment: ```Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');``` should i put my route inside this group middleware

Comment: This is not a group but the syntax for adding the middleware seems correct. you can do the same for your rout but it would be cleaner to create a group `Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () { // your routes here});`I have updated my answer

Comment: can this affect validation because after adding ```@if(Auth::check())
    <h5 class="mb-0 text-white nav-user-name">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
        {{ Auth::user()->email }}
    </h5>
@endif``` validation is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199894/discussion-between-mike-and-harristars).

Comment: i still get the same error even after doing this ```@if(Auth::check())
    <h5 class="mb-0 text-white nav-user-name">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
        {{ Auth::user()->email }}
    </h5>
@endif```

Answer (score 0):

Is your query returning array or object? If you dump it out, you might find that it's an array and all you need is an array access ([]) instead of an object access (->).

Comment: `Auth::user()` returns the current user model or `null` if no user is logged in.